# map value in a new pandas column with a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have the following dictionary

```
entdict = { 'Toto': [1,30624],'Titi': [1,35001],'Tata': [0,90731],
            'Tutut': [0,28679] 
           }
```

I would like create a new column in the following dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Subject':['Titi','Tutut', 'Tata','Toto'], 
                'study_id':['S10', 'S11', 'S12', 'S13'], 
                'ent':[1, 0, 0, 1]})
```

I would like to map the dictionary and create a new column in df by mapping the 'Subject' column.
I tried the following line of code (which worked with the following dictionary.

```
entdict = { 'Toto': 1,'Titi': 1,'Tata': 0,
            'Tutut': 0
           }
```

## mapping a dictionary

df['ent'] = df['Subject'].map(entdict)

```
How could I do it with a dictionary such as the first one described above which contains more than one value for each keys?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map lists and then select first values by indexing with `str[0]`:

```
df['ent'] = df['Subject'].map(entdict).str[0]
```

Or you can create helper dictionary:

```
d = {k:v[0] for k, v in entdict.items()}
df['ent'] = df['Subject'].map(d)
print (df)
  Subject study_id  ent
0    Titi      S10    1
1   Tutut      S11    0
2    Tata      S12    0
3    Toto      S13    1
```